# Backbone Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toJSON' of undefined Unable to get the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am trying to build an application in rails with Backbone. I am facing a problem where I get an undefined on the model where i try to read it.

Here is my code.

// Collection

```
Quizzer.Collections.Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({

   model: Quizzer.Models.Post,
   url: "/posts"

});
```

// Model

```
Quizzer.Models.Post = Backbone.Model.extend({

});
```

//PostIndex View

```
Quizzer.Views.PostsIndex = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: JST['posts/index'],
    el: '#posts',

    render: function(){
        $(this.el).html(this.template);
        $(this.projectsCallView());
        return this;
    },

    projectsCallView: function(){
        var pp = new Quizzer.Views.Posts({ collection : new Quizzer.Collections.Posts });
        this.$("ul").append(pp.render().el)
    }

});
```

//Posts View

```
Quizzer.Views.Posts = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#container',

    template: JST['posts/posts'],

    initialize: function(){
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);   
        this.collection.fetch({ reset:true });
        },

    render:function(){
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        _.each(this.collection,this.addOne);
        return this;
    },

    addOne: function(model){
        console.log(model);
        var vv = new Quizzer.Views.PostW({ model: model })
        $("ul").append(vv.render().el)
    }

});
```

//PostW View

```
Quizzer.Views.PostW = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: JST['posts/postsw'],

    render: function() {
        console.log(this.model)
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

Can you tell where my problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
_.each(this.collection,this.addOne);
```

do

```
this.collection.each(this.addOne);
```

Comment: ok that worked but now there appeared another problem in the console:
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'template' of object [object Object] is not a function in postw View. What can be wrong with it?

Comment: That depends on what's in the array value JST['posts/postsw']. I'm guessing you've copied the line which throws the error from some backbone example which uses underscore as the templating engine. Since _.template(...) returns a function which takes the placeholders as a parameter, they can call the function like that. What's the value you have stored in JST['posts/postsw']?

Comment: I found the error on that line. I wrote postsw instead od postw. Typo. Thanks a lot